# Translation of python API request to Java not working

Tags: java, python, api

I'm trying to replicate, using Java, a very simple Python function that calls a remote service. I don't have the service documentation. Here's the Python code:

```
def sendImage(addr, image_path):
    image = open(image_path, 'rb').read()
    files = { 'image': ('Image.jpg', image, 'image/jpg') }
    response = requests.post(addr, files = files)
    print(response.text)
```

But I can't seem to get this to work. Here's my Java code so far:

```
try {

    URL url = new URL(request);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
    connection.setConnectTimeout(Constants.TIMEOUT);
    connection.setReadTimeout(Constants.TIMEOUT);
    try (OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream()) {
        IOUtils.copy(image, out);
    }
    try (InputStream in = connection.getInputStream()) {
        Map<String, String> originalResponse = mapper.readValue(in, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructMapType(HashMap.class, String.class, String.class));
    }

}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm calling both functions with the same addr and using the same image, but when I run my Java code, the app hangs in this line for a few seconds

```
try (InputStream in = connection.getInputStream()) {
```

and then I get a "400: Bad Request" response.

Why is this not working, and how can I make it work? Thanks in advance

Comment: Compare the network traffic to see the difference in the requests. You're getting a 400 Bad Request.

Comment: K, gonna download wireshark and see what's going on

Comment: Excellent idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response = requests.post(addr, files = files)` is [file upload with multipart encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526286/344141) (see [api reference](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.request)) and in your java code you just write file content as body of request.

If you want to write code to properly handle multipart request, then check out [this RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html), what you must include in request body.

My suggestion would be to use some http client. [Here is example of upload with okhttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#posting-a-multipart-request-kt-java).

Comment: Thanks, will look into it and report back

Comment: After modifying the sample code a bit, I got it to work. Thanks for the help!